# Changes in array Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I have updated to swift 2 and the migration tool has not been able to update my arrays. Here is where I am getting the errors:

```
        actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alien.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))

        actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())
        actionArray2.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alienAzul.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))

        actionArray2.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())
```

This is what it says:

> Value of type '[SKAction]' has no member 'addObject'

Comment: Are u using NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices for Swift is to use Arrays as follows:

Define your array variable as

```
var actionArray: [SKAction]!
```

Instantiate it:

```
actionArray = [SKAction]()
```

Add objects to it with:

```
actionArray.append(sKAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `append(newElement: Element)`